# JSON x Web Services

Tags: android, json, ios, xml, services

1 - Qual a diferença de JSON para Web Services? (Apenas o tipo de formato no retorno)?

2 - Em termos de performance, qual seria melhor?

3 - Na prática devo usar JSON (com um arquivo php ou java por exemplo) para integrar minhas aplicações direto com AJAX ou Mobile (Ios e Android) e Web Services quando quero que outras pessoas tenham acesso a ele?

Obrigada

Answer (score 2):

Não é uma questão de "diferença".

Web services são "API's" para acessar dados através de protocolo HTTP. Qualquer forma de comunicação sobre HTTP para transferir dados entre aplicações pode ser chamada de web service.

Existem várias maneiras de estruturar a sua "API" usando HTTP como meio de transporte. A indústria desenvolveu e adotou o [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), usando um conjunto enorme de protocolos para trocar informação em XML sobre HTTP. SOAP ganhou um viés muito corporativo e ficou complexo, então alguns desenvolvedores adotam [XML-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC), que é mais informal.

Inicialmente, se usava XML mesmo quando o cliente da API era uma aplicação web em um browser, mas eventualmente caiu a ficha de que decodificar XML no browser era muito pesado e que seria mais simples entregar o conteúdo em [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), que nada mais é que a estrutura de dados nativa do Javascript.

Então JSON é só o formato de transferência de dados usado por web services. Se seus web services forem consumidos por aplicações em browsers, é natural que você opte por JSON. Se forem consumidos por outras aplicações, talvez XML faça mais sentido. Como os dois são apenas formatos para a mesma informação, os frameworks de desenvolvimento (Rails, por exemplo) costumam permitir que o mesmo web service retorne JSON ou XML de acordo com a solicitação do cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Você está confundindo as coisas. Web service é um ponto de acesso de um dispositivo (um servidor por exemplo) para outros dispositivos (navegadores ou outros servidores) na WWW, já JSON é um formato para representação de dados. Webservices podem utilizar JSON ou algum outro formato para (XML, YAML, HTML, texto puro, etc) para transmitir dados, ou podem aceitar dados de entrada em algum (ou vários) destes formatos.

A pergunta que você quer fazer é provavelmente "qual protocolo de comunicação devo usar para meu webservice, REST, SOAP ou outro?" e "qual formato de transferência de dados seria o mais aconselhado?", nesse caso meu conselho é para que use [REST](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) como protocolo de comunicação (que é basicamente apenas HTTP) e JSON como formato de dados.